# Listview navigation in Android

Tags: android

I have a custom Listview in my android app and on list item click, I'm able to navigate to other activity, which shows all the details about list item !! Now my question is, I want to navigate to next/previous listitem's details through second activity.. how can i do this.??

I'm new to android and stackoverflow as well..

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is more of a design question, so i'll answer that way -
Your best bet will be to use something like a `ViewPager` in the new activity, which receives the selected item position and displays it with underlying adapter having the same items from the previous activity. using the `ViewPager` the user can swipe left and right between items.
For a good example on this usage, you might want to take a look at "Google Reader" on Play Store which has this exact same design pattern.

Comment: Let me see.. !!
But that is available in API 13+ (maybe) !!
Do you got any other way for my query ?

Comment: You can use the support library so it will work on lower APIs aswell